# PictureCallback is being fired from main thread

Tags: android

I'm using in my app android.hardware.Camera to take picture.
I'm wondering why the PictureCallback's method that i provided to function is being fired from the Main thread ?
how can i fire this callback from background thread ?
thanks

Answer (score 4):

> I'm wondering why the PictureCallback's method that i provided to function is being fired from the Main thread ?

Because pretty much all callbacks to you are on the main application thread.

> how can i fire this callback from background thread ?

You can't AFAIK. If you are doing something long with the picture (e.g., writing it to flash, streaming it over the network), fork your own thread from `onPictureTaken()`. [Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Camera/Picture) that uses an `AsyncTask` for this.

Comment: hhmm.. this is a problem. My main flow calls (on the main thread) takePicture() and then preform other logic (like mails sending). this means that the callback will be fire after that logic will end.

Comment: @spenser: The move the "other logic" to `onPictureTaken()`.

Comment: @JannieT: Actually, if you like that, I am working on a reusable camera library you might be interested in: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera